# MongoDB: Find all records with special characters in a particular field

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am getting the following error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: $regex has to be a
> string

Below is my code:

```
let dbData = await client
      .db('skreem-final')
      .collection('influencers')
      .countDocuments({
        firstName: {
          $regex: !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      });
    // console.log(name, !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(name));
    console.log(dbData);
    // });
```

Comment: Did you try enclosing whole regex inside quotes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing your regex into `" "`:

```
$regex: "!/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g",
```